# Pandas: left join multiple dfs and update NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with IDs

```
   id
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

and need to "left-join" (or left-merge) several data frames to it, one after another.

```
    id   text
0    1  Hello
1    2  World
2  100  Hello
```

and

```
    id   text
0    3  World
1  101  Hello
```

**Note: I can not load all dfs at once because of RAM.**

A standard "left-join"...

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,100],
                    'text': ['Hello', 'World','Hello']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [3,101],
                    'text': ['World', 'Hello']})

m1 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on="id", how="left")
m2 = pd.merge(left=m1, right=df3, on="id", how="left")
```

...gives me:

```
   id text_x text_y
0   1  Hello    NaN
1   2  World    NaN
2   3    NaN  World
3   4    NaN    NaN
```

However, I would like to "update" the right-joined column so that I get:

```
   id text
0   1  Hello
1   2  World
2   3  World
3   4    NaN
```

Is there a way to do this with pd.merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more like a `update` problem

```
df1['text']=np.nan
df1.set_index('id',inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('id'))
df1.update(df3.set_index('id'))
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1
Out[54]: 
   id   text
0   1  Hello
1   2  World
2   3  World
3   4    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

First we use `np.where` to conditionally fill our `text` column, after that we drop the columns we dont need.

```
m2['text'] = np.where(m2.text_x.isnull(), m2.text_y, m2.text_x)
m2.drop(['text_x', 'text_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)


    id  text
0   1   Hello
1   2   World
2   3   World
3   4   NaN
```

**Explanation**

`np.where` works as following:
`np.where(condition, true value, false value)`